# c# Very Long URL cant be be bound. Some Parameters get 0/null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Please advise what can be the reason for leaving some parameters out of binding. 
I have set both required configurations. But it doesnot resolve issue.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxQueryStringLength="64768" maxUrlLength="70536" />
```

.....

```
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="64768" />
```

Please advise and comments are welcome

Comment: And how long is your url?

Comment: Maybe the URL is already truncated in the browser? Then the server settings would make no difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1450855

Comment: My advice would be to change the GET request to a POST, so the query parameters need not be part of the URL.

Comment: Georg Patscheider. But the raw url comes appropriate. unforetunely, it is not possible to change get to post